# jquery requests

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code

```
$.post('data.php'{"request":"data_"+$(this).attr("data")},function(data){
  $("div").text(data);
});
```

But if somebody else can call my website like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.website.com/data.php',
    data: { request: "data_1" },
    success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
    }
```

He can easily get mine data.
How prevent this?

Comment: JavaScript cannot make cross-domain Ajax calls by default. The server must explicitly allow it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. Of course anyone can use their browser or tools like `curl` to request the data. The question is, why do you need to protect the data?

Comment: Your answer will have to go far beyond just jQuery. You need some authentication or blocking at the server level. What server are you running? (Apache, tomcat, iis etc.) What version of php?

Comment: @FelixKling that restriction is easily defeated. The incoming request doesn't even have to be a js request, you could use a tool like fiddler to forge the request.

Comment: and what about php? can somebody take the data width php?

Comment: Some one could also screen scrape the data from the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browsers won't let cross domain requests happen.
regarding serverside scraping there's not much you can do, you could check to allow only browser's user agents but ultimately anything can be faked with the right tools (it's just an http request at the end of the day).
Of course if you notice spike in traffic from certain hosts you can disable access from those.
If you want to prevent framing you can add

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
```

to htaccess